# Find a general form of a subplane

Tags: plane-geometry

I am trying to find a general form of a subplane $ x=2+5t$ ,  $ y=3$, $ t \in \mathbb{R}$.I know how to find a general form of a line, but not a plane. Could you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The equation is given by $$y=3$$

Comment: Is the result -y+3=0?

Comment: Yes this is true.